Programmable filter to add time dependent Cell/Point data to vtu/pvtu unstructured grid in paraview
I wrote a python programmable filter in paraview that, given an unstructured grid object (vtu/pvtu original format) and a paraview extraction of points/cells, modifies the value of the user-selected cell/point data in the selected points of the grid:
dof = "ax_bc"
value = 1.0

import vtk
import numpy as np
# Example usage
input0 = inputs[0]
input1 = inputs[1]

# Get the input data objects
if input0 is None or input1 is None:
    raise ValueError("One or both input VTK objects are missing.")

# Get the point data arrays
point_data0 = input0.GetPointData()
point_data1 = input1.GetPointData()

# Get the "array one" point data array in the first input
array_one = point_data0.GetArray(dof)
if array_one is None:
    raise ValueError("The first input VTK object does not have a " + dof + " array.")

# Get the vtkOriginalPointIds array from the second input
original_ids = point_data1.GetArray("vtkOriginalPointIds")
if original_ids is None:
    raise ValueError(
        "The second input VTK object does not have a 'vtkOriginalPointIds' array."
    )

# Convert VTK arrays to NumPy arrays
if np.any((original_ids < 0) | (original_ids >= input0.GetNumberOfPoints())):
    raise IndexError("One or more original IDs are out of bounds for the first input VTK object.")

# Assign values to the dofs based on the original ids
array_one[original_ids] = value

point_data0.append(array_one, dof)
point_data0.Modified()

Now I would like to use another programmable filter (or if not possible, a paraview shell script or python script) to add (set new cell/point data and modify) time-dependent cell/point data to my grid. I've found very poor documentation on how to use time in python/vtu unstructured grids and make it readable for paraview. For instance, I would want to add a point data array "ax_bc" as a time dependent array. Which way should I follow?
I've found some solutions involving multiblock datasets, but I've also read of subsequent problems when parallelization is involved (I will need to export to pvtu format).

In a programmable filter, you can get the current pipeline time and then set the data array accordingly.
executive = self.GetExecutive()
outInfo = executive.GetOutputInformation(0)
return outInfo.Get(executive.UPDATE_TIME_STEP()) if outInfo.Has(executive.UPDATE_TIME_STEP()) else None

If you want to create timesteps (i.e. your input is not temporal but the output should be), then you should add a RequestInformation script. In this script, set the TIME_STEPS() and TIME_RANGE() information key to provide to full time values list.
See the example here: https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/ReferenceManual/pythonProgrammableFilter.html#reading-a-csv-file-series

Thanks! What of I wanted to modify my original vtk grid directly and make it time dependent?

If you mean creating a temporal file that you can open in ParaView, look at this doc: https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/dataIngestion.html#handling-temporal-file-series

This is to save the file names but how do I actually write a code to write a series of files to make it appear time dependent in paraview, let's stay starting from a python unstructured grid object?

with the native VTK file format, you need to write one file per timestep with an incrementing number in the filename (pattern is described in my previous link). Then you should be able to open it as a temporal file in ParaView

about VTK file formats: https://docs.vtk.org/en/latest/design_documents/VTKFileFormats.html

I know the formats and this web page is the first thing you find when searching in the web, nothing new or useful for my purpose. I am not finding a way to actually modify my original data and make it time dependent. You suggested  how to add a TIME_RANGE and TIME_SETS, but how do I actually modify my Cell/Point Data arrays once I added the time to my output grid?
